# Need some clarify on uninitialized variable

Tags: c++

I got my code here and I have tried to run it in visual studio a couple times and it keeps saying that "uninitialized local variable 'userNum' used" at line 10 but when I run it on the online c++ compiler, it runs just fine. Can you guys help me with this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int userNum;
    int i = 0;
    int min;

    cout << "Please enter your number: ";

    while (userNum != 0) {
        cin >> userNum; 
        if (i == 0) {
            min = userNum;

        }

        else {
            if (userNum < min && userNum != 0) {
                min = userNum;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Smallest: " << min;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`int userNum`

What you are doing here is declaring a variable but not initializing a value to it. Then you try to use this uninitialized variable in your while statement. Whatever the online compiler says, this is not good practice.

Change this statement to `int userNum = (some value)`

Comment: Hello, I just change it like what you said it runs perfectly now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Worst than not good practice, reading uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.